# How do you remove the new line code (&#10;) with php?

Tags: php

Ok, so I was tasked with created a gallery, using a sql table is not an option, so I am doing what I can. This is my code, wich works fine, but it generates a hidden character at the end of every imate.

```
<?php
    $photos = file("/elements/photos.php");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($photos); $i++) {
    $allimages .= $imagefile =  '<img src="/elements/photos/'.$photos[$i].'">';};
?>

<?=$allimages?>
```

This is the code that it generates

```
<img src="/elements/photos/t/a_little_kitten.jpg&#10;">
```

I have been unable to find what 
 this means, I believe it means "blank space" or "new line", but I cannot find it.

This is the code I have tried, but it does not work either.

```
$allimages = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $allimages)
```

Please help.

Below is the php file I am pulling the image names from. There is no code in this file, just text.

```
a_little_kitten.jpg
black_cat.jpg
basket.jpg
```

Comment: What if you just fix the original data that contains those extra characters?

Comment: It is a hidden character, I have tried everything.

Comment: Show us the `photos.php` script?

Comment: I added it. There is no special code, just the name of the images.

Comment: I copied your code and your data file and it output without any extra characters.

Comment: you can try using the `trim()` function around the photo variable.

Comment: Did you try that? `$allimages = preg_replace('/\n/', '', $allimages);`

Comment: For everyone that suggests removing a new line character: please try it first before you suggest. https://3v4l.org/r9cLU

Answer (score 0):

Try `rtrim` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) or `trim` to remove the whitespace. As I can see that there is a whitespace at the end of your `a_little_kitten.jpg` and `black_cat.jpg` file.

&#10 represents a line feed. Maybe you can use `str_replace()`
ex: `str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $photos)` before `for` loop.

Comment: Why would `trim` remove any of these characters: `&#10;`?

Comment: The newline comes from the use of the `file()` function which leaves the \n (0x0A) at the end of each array element. Calling trim will get rid of it and that is what the &#10;

Comment: `&#10;` is not a new line character, it's 5 characters, literally.

Comment: No but its the html entity for a newline so if they call trim in the foreach, the newline won't be part of the IMG src in the HTML.

Comment: So how the `\x10` character turned into html entity? Do you realise the `trim` function does not clean up html entity `&#10`? Have you tried to `trim` a string with such an html entity?